# how to centralize two images and add some text between them

Tags: html, css, css-position

i am a beginner.i have two images, i tired to centralize them and add text between them but nothing seems to be working.i tried to use "inline-block" and "position:absolute".[This image might help you to understand what i am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIT9o.jpg)

Comment: show us what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a flexbox:

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
.container span {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"/>
  <span>Some text</span>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"/>
</div>
```